# How do I prevent any app from being installed on an android device?

Tags: applications, google-pixel

There's a similar question which discusses preventing app installs on the device.

I'd like to prevent any app from being installed, as a child will be using it, including from a computer at play.google.com.

I tried using Family link but it only allows preventing app installs rated PG13 and above.

Can I prevent the android device from accepting any new apps?

Comment: You should expand on the use case for app prevention: e.g. letting a child borrow a phone, corporate device restriction, for use as a kiosk, etc.

Comment: It's a device that's used by a child

Comment: So Family Link's "All Content" approval requirement isn't sufficient? https://support.google.com/families/answer/7039872